# How to Read Numerical, Minute and Second Values from File, While Writing Values *Exactly As Given* To Other File

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

First off, is it possible?

To extrapolate the question: I'd like to read some integers from a file, which is relatively simple for me. 
However, when I read these values, which are formatted: "123 17 24 55 04 30 09" for example, my written output shows "123 17 24 55 4 30 9", where the "0" is absent before the 4, and the 9. This bothers me from a formatting aspect. How do I retain the 0 which is infront of the 4, and 9, in my output?

My current code is attached

````
int main() {

ifstream inf;
ofstream of;
float timeSmin, timeSsec, timeBmin, timeBsec=01.00, timeRmin=01, timeRsec=01.00;
int ID, totaltime;


inf.open ("triath.txt");
of.open ("output.txt");

if (!inf.is_open()){
  cout << "Triath.txt cannot be opened, error..." << endl;
}

inf >> ID >> timeSmin >> timeSsec >> timeBmin >> timeBsec >> timeRmin >> timeRsec; //writing values to input object.

of << ID << " " << timeSmin << " " << timeSsec << " " << timeBmin << " " << timeBsec << " " << timeRmin << " " << timeRsec;


inf.close();
of.close();
return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file in as a string and parse the string. That gives you the original string to use for output.

You'll need a way of splitting your input string into tokens. If you can't figure that out, you can do a google for "c++ split string by spaces" and get a bunch of good hits.

You'll need to then convert substrings into integers. Again, a google for "c++ convert string to integer" will provide some clues.

Then you just output the original string as is, and it's identical to what you originally read.

Comment: Thank you Joseph, where I study I don't use terminology such as parse, and token, so I don't know what you meant, thank you for the expert advice, and in the future I'd recommend expanding more on terminology such as that so that we can learn more efficiently.

Comment: @John-PaulAnderson I can't really anticipate when someone might be a non-native-English speaker. I can't really help with language translation. Parse and token are common words in English.